# (:var 0) in z3 Quantifier's body

Tags: z3

When I get the body of a Quantifier of the Z3 OCaml API, for example a Quantifier whose string is

```
(exists ((u_1 Int)) (= u_1 x5))
```

by Quantifier.get_body, I obtain the expression

```
(= (:var 0) x5)
```

I guess (:var 0) in this expression is the renaming of u_1 to a fresh variable, but I do not know what is the kind of the expression (:var 0) and how to match it back to u_1 when we want to reconstruct the Quantifier from its body and its bound variables.

Could anyone suggest a solution? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution. The expression e

```
(:var 0)
```

is an expression of VAR_AST. You can check by

```
AST.is_var (Expr.ast_of_expr e)
```

Then, you can get its index, e.g., 0, by

```
Quantifier.get_index e
```

With the index, you can easily match the expression e to its bound variable. Note that the list of bound variables of a quantifier can be obtained by

```
Quantifier.get_bound_variable_names
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer. Please consider doing so, to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: That's right, thanks for figuring it out yourself :-)